# Marketing cloud user permissions :

Tags: marketing-cloud

When a permission is neither granted nor denied, does Marketing Cloud default to denying the permission to the user or not?
Can anyone please answer?

Answer (score 2):

> An explicitly denied permission always overrides all other permissions. When a permission is not explicitly granted or denied, Marketing Cloud defaults to a deny permission unless another role grants that permission.

Source: [Marketing Cloud Roles](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_overview_marketing_cloud_roles.htm&type=5)